# Alternatives to parse and eval to check syntactic correctness for Julia v 1.1

Tags: julia

Julia is dynamically typed and certain errors only occur during execution.

For instance:

```
julia> function foo()
       a
       5
       end
foo (generic function with 1 method)

julia> foo()
ERROR: UndefVarError: a not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] foo() at ./REPL[1]:2
 [2] top-level scope at none:0

julia>
```

Same behaviour using parse in combination with eval:

```
julia> eval(Meta.parse("function foo()
       a
       5
       end"))
foo (generic function with 1 method)
```

However, when executing this an error is thrown:

```
julia> foo()
ERROR: UndefVarError: a not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] foo() at ./none:2
 [2] top-level scope at none:0
```

Does it exist any standard facilities to check against these kinds of errors? Or does it exist any suitable packages for this task?

Answer (score 1):

The [VS Code Julia extension](https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode) has an [integrated linter](https://github.com/julia-vscode/StaticLint.jl) that can detect usage of undefined variables, as in your example.

There is also this linter, [Lint.jl](https://lintjl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), though I am not sure if it's up-to-date for Julia v1.x.

Comment: Upvoted. However, as you stated there seem to be issues with Lint.jl for the more recent versions of Julia